# Downloading Images from Google Drive using Google Drive Android API?

Tags: android, image, download, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Basically, I have been using this guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro

I have gotten the picture to upload into drive with the help of: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/tree/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo

However, the GitHub project linked above does not provide any way to retrieve Images from Drive, it only shows text files. I am aware of the QueryNonTextFilesActivity.java but this gives the result in MetaDataBuffer which is appended onto ResultsAdapter. My question is: how do I use this data and convert to images (.png)?

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a [DriveId](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveId) from when you inserted the image, you can then retrieve the file using [Drive.DriveApi.getFile()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi#getFile(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId)) - this returns you a [DriveFile](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFile.html).

Once you have a `DriveFile`, you can get an `InputStream` to the contents of the file as a Bitmap using [open()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveFile#open(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20int,%20com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFile.DownloadProgressListener)) and code such as

```
file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
    .setResultCallback(
      new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
          // Handle an error
        }
        DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
        InputStream is = driveContents.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        // Do something with the bitmap

        // Don't forget to close the InputStream
        is.close();
      });
```