# trying to create an Image Picker for android with cloud support.

Tags: android, cloud

I want that the user should be able to see his cloud images (from google drive,one drive, drop box, etc) along with images stored on device. I have already written an image picker that picks device images, the problem is to get the cloud images. I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see this link i think you find your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689077/downloading-images-from-google-drive-using-google-drive-android-api

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the official Rest API provided by the organizations?
[Check the official samples.](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)  It can easily be integrated with your original app.